# How to modify the content of an xml file in SharePoint Online by powershell

Tags: powershell, document-library, xml

I would like to fix some xml files seperated on multiple sites and document libraries in powershell. I have in a csv file the url of all these xml documents. So I already have some loop for each xml path. But how can I modify the content of these xml files? Do I need to download the file, modify it local and upload it again?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, we need to download the XML file and update as per your need then upload back to the same location:

For update sample, you can refer the below PowerShell:

```
$Path = "\\spsite\sites\subsite\Library\"
$Files = Get-ChildItem $Path | where {$_.extension -eq ".xml"}
foreach($file in $Files){
    $xml = New-Object XML
    $xml.PreserveWhitespace = $true
    $xml.Load($file.fullname)
    $xml.myFields.PhoneNumber = "234-5678"//update your fields on the form
    $xml.Save($file.fullname)
}
```

Reference:

[Powershell to replace text in infopath XML files](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/Lync/en-US/3afce6f0-a4b8-415b-91c4-97a2644d8d09/powershell-to-replace-text-in-infopath-xml-files?forum=sharepointdevelopmentprevious)

**OR**

If your XML files are relatively smaller in size - then you may use the **MemoryStream** - MemoryStream sample as below:

```
$Stream = New-Object System.IO.MemoryStream
$UDCX.Save($Stream)
$document.SaveBinary($Stream.ToArray())
```

Reference:

[Using powershell to read/modify/rewrite sharepoint xml document](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14905396/using-powershell-to-read-modify-rewrite-sharepoint-xml-document)